# Permission denied adding SSH key to .ssh/config

Tags: terminal, macos, permission, ssh

I am trying to add SSH key to `~/.ssh/config` using `echo "IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key" >> ~/.ssh/config`

It is showing me error `-bash: /Users/gaurav/.ssh/config: Permission denied`

What i am doing wrong?

Permission to folders

```
total 64
-rw-r--r--  1 root    staff    85 Apr 15 12:59 config
-rw-------  1 gaurav  staff  1766 Jan  4 23:11 github_rsa
-rw-r--r--@ 1 gaurav  staff   404 Mar 20 09:50 github_rsa.pub
-r--------  1 gaurav  staff  1766 Mar 20 10:05 google-sb-server
-rw-r--r--  1 gaurav  staff   388 Mar 20 10:05 google-sb-server.pub
-rw-------  1 gaurav  staff  3247 Jan  5 10:37 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 gaurav  staff   726 Jan  5 10:37 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 gaurav  staff  2230 Mar 20 12:45 known_hosts
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The config file in ~/.ssh/ has the wrong owner/permissions. It's owned by root.

Change the owner to gaurav with:

```
sudo chown gaurav:staff ~/.ssh/config
```

enter your password and it will work (if you are a sudoer).

Comment: It is completed thanks . Now i am able to do . Once more thing giving ownership to current_user is it safe in case of SSH

Comment: @twister_void I don't really understand your question in the comment. Please add a second question regarding security issues (of the config file?) on the main (apple.stackexchange) site.

Answer (score 2):

- Home directory on the server should not be writable by others: `chmod go-w ~/`
- SSH folder on the server needs 700 permissions: `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
- Authorized_keys file needs 644 permissions: `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Make sure that `gaurav` owns the files/folders and not `root`: `chown user:gaurav authorized_keys` and `chown user:gaurav ~/.ssh`
- Put the generated public key (from `ssh-keygen`) in the user's `authorized_keys` file on the server
- Make sure that user's home directory is set to what you expect it to be and that it contains the correct `.ssh` folder that you've been modifying. If not, use `usermod -d ~/ gaurav` to fix the issue
- Finally, restart ssh: `service ssh restart`
- Then make sure client has the public key and private key files in the local user's `.ssh` folder and login: `ssh gaurav@host.com`

Best of Luck!